# My manipulate axis is skewed

Tags: modeling

[image]I must have accidentally hit a shortcut for a setting, but my axis is off and when scaling, I'll press <kbd>X</kbd>  to scale on the X axis and my shape will be skewed.

My 3d manipulator tool is off at an angle and I can't figure out how to reset it or change it back.

Comment: It is likely a screen capture of your problem will help you get a quicker answer.  A new contributor can make life easier for the contributor with the screen capture .  Make sure you include the menu and tool bars.

Comment: Its it good that you have an image. Now show a better image with menus and the global axis showing.  Without the global axis or grid showing ... orientation is just a guessing game .. a bad game.  Try the different views on your numeric keypad.  Show the rotation as well in the object panel.  Show more to provide clues to the reader.  At this early point in your Blender training ... the above information is essential.  Many readers will will perceive your images as demonstrating to little effort in communicating the problem.

Comment: Here is a video tutorial .... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zHdTUJBs7so .. It may be Blender 2.7 yet still valuable.  He has a whole video tutorial series.

Comment: Is the above object valuable in terms of the time dedicated to it? ...  Can you just have a fresh start?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider pressing the different keys on your numeric keypad.
This will align your view to an axis in the set {XYZ}.

<kbd>NumberPad 1</kbd>
<kbd>NumberPad 3</kbd>
<kbd>NumberPad 7</kbd> with/without the variation of 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/align.html

---

Consider changing the

transformation orientation to

[Global]

as indicated by the yellow arrow.

Sometimes a rogue keystroke or click can change a setting unbeknownst to many.

If your 3D mesh above is not time consuming ... I would just consider archiving mesh file. Similar to a delete. Create a new file and start over.  You probably wont make the same mistake.  Starting over may be more cost effective than chasing down one little small problem and trying to remember your actions or describe it.

Comment: In Global it is set up correct. But if I try to set origin to geometry it goes back to this skewed angle. I will post screen shots.